# Matching log entries across multiple lines in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to search a log file that contains log entries that span multiple lines. Example:

```
BEGIN
...
123456
...
END
BEGIN
...
456789
...
END
```

I want to search for a specific number (123456) but print everything from the preceding BEGIN tag to the END tag. How can I accomplish this in PowerShell?

I tried several regular expressions but haven't gotten it to work. The code I have so far is:

```
$id = '123456'

$pattern = 'BEGIN(.|\s)*?'+$id+'(.|\s)*?END'

$matches = Select-String -Path "C:\temp\logile.log" -Pattern $pattern
```

Not sure why this isn't working. Is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: I think you need modifiers since it matches across lines. `$pattern = '(?m)BEGIN(.|\s)*?'+$id+'(.|\s)*?END'
`

Comment: Could also do this `(?sm)BEGIN.*?123456.*?END`

Comment: Depending on what you were doing with the data you could just split the file on begin and analyze the "blocks" that way as well. Only if you are doing more than what you show here.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you want a regex that must encompass newline characters maybe using the `Get-Content` with the `-raw` switch might be the way to go. I have included that there must be be a newline before and after the search text to avoid partial matches.

```
$id = '123456'
$pattern = '(?<=BEGIN)(.|[\n\r])+?\r\n' + $id + '\r\n(.|[\n\r])+?(?=END)'
[regex]::Match((Get-Content "C:\temp\logile.log" -Raw), $pattern).value
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the log into sections with a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
foreach ($Section in (Get-Content C:\temp\logile.log -raw) -split '(?<=END\r?\n?)' -ne ''){
    if($section -match '123456'){
        $Section
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
BEGIN
...
123456
...
END
```